# Forbid access to other users' files on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm developing a React Native application where users will upload files to Amazon S3 and later retrieve them. My biggest concern right now is how to implement this mechanism in a way that only the OWNER of the file can access it.

My first idea was implement a middle server to control all access to Amazon S3 server, but this would demand a lot of time/work to make the server secure.

My second idea was to create an IAM token for every new user and create folders with the right permissions that only the owner of the folder will have access to it. But researching on the limitations of Amazon IAM service, I found that the maximum number of IAM accounts for each AWS account is 5000.

Is there a better approach for this situation than the first one? If not, what MUST be done to make the server secure and keep the files on Amazon S3 safe?

Comment: This might help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/, or using Cognito: https://medium.com/@inishant/access-to-user-level-folders-using-amazon-s3-and-cognito-469e80dce4c6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have at this post https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

effectively you can prefix file names (s3 keys) with the user id and write s3 policy to let users access (read or write) only files with their user id (there is such s3 policy somewhere, I am unable to find it now, just search for it)

> limitations of Amazon IAM service

you can use AWS Cognito to authenticate users outside IAM limitations and having common policies for the user store

Comment: Decided to use AWS Cognito. Works fine for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

From [IAM FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/):

> Q: How many IAM roles can I create? You are limited to 1,000 IAM roles
> under your AWS account.
>
> If you need more roles, submit the IAM [limit
> increase request](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/iam-limit-increase-request) form with your use case, and we will consider your
> request.

Also not sure what your usecase is but S3 also supports temporary [signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Signed URLs doesn't fit my needs because I need more than 1000 IAM roles. Cognito was the way to go.